# ColdFusion 11 Express Installation and Setup

Tags: coldfusion, wamp, coldfusion-11

I am new to ColdFusion. I want to start by installating and setting up the environment. And test a dummy page on it.

I downloaded the express edition version 11 from the adobe website "ColdFusion_exp_11_WWEJ_win64". But I don't see a installer or something. It's just one big folder. Sorry for a noob question, but what do I do with it? I have a WAMP server on my computer. How does it run this?

How do I test a page to see if it is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Too long for comments)

> found the cfstart.bat and when I click it, it opens the console and
>   then closes it

When you run `cfstart.bat`, the console should stay open, unless something is wrong. For example, if the default port 8500 is already in use. Run `cfstart.bat` file in cmd.exe so you can view the errors. If that is the issue, item #4a in the link Adam posted contains instructions on how to change the port number:

> ... if [the] default port (8500) for the built-in web server is
>   already in use, the Express edition will not start. To change the port
>   see the `<ARCHIVE_ROOT>\cfusion\runtime\conf\server.xml` file and edit
>   the port on the line starting with `<Connector port="8500" ...`. Save the
>   file and return to step 2.

The .bat file's job is just to start up the CF server. Once it is running (ie console stays open without error), you will work through the browser. See the instructions in the link for how to configure CF via the CF Admin. You  can run CFML code by creating `.cfm` files within the `wwwroot` directory. Ultimately, you will want to use an IDE for writing CFML code, but for now you can use any text editor, like notepad. Just be sure to save the files with a .cfm extension, NOT .txt.

For example, enter the following code: `<cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>` and save it to a file named "test.cfm" beneath the wwwroot directory:  `{cf_root}\wwwroot\test.cfm`. Then view it your browser by entering: http://127.0.0.1:8500/test.cfm (where 8500 whatever port number you end up using).  If CF is running properly, it should display the current date and time:

```
    {ts '2015-08-29 15:02:47'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I googled "how to start coldfusion express" and the first link explains it all: "[Installing ColdFusion Express](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Installing+ColdFusion+Express)".

There's not much to it. In the cfusion/bin dir there's a cfstart.bat. Run it.

I have, coincidentally, done this very tasks just this evening, and can confirm that's all there is to it. Read through those docs though.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmMO7abCp6I, yeah I found this and I am running on wamp. It seems to work.  Except wamp is not starting now.

Comment: @SaadA - Which version did you download? As Adam said, the "Express" version (which you mentioned in your question) is specifically designed to run *without* an installer. Just click a .bat file and it it runs. The link you posted is for a different version, which *does* require installation.

Comment: ok, so I found the cfstart.bat and when I click it, it opens the  console and then closes it. But now how do I run a page on it? Sorry Again if this is a stupid question. Appreciate any help

Comment: Right, so as Leigh points out, you need to run the batch file from the actual command-line interface so that you can see what it outputs when it exits prematurely; if you run it from the Windows UI, as soon as it exits the Window will close (which is what you're seeing). Also check the log files for any indication of what went wrong.